# How to get latitude and longitude of Point plotted on the map using mapbox

Tags: cartography, java

How can I retrieve the longitude and latitude of a point plotted on map? I am testing one website in which I need to verify the longitude and latitude of a point plotted on the map.

Map has been developed using Mapbox.

Comment: What does java have to do with this question? Also, how are you accessing the map?

Comment: Do you have access to the codebase or are you testing a third party site? (kind of goes along with "how are you accessing the map")

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean in JavaScript, I think I can help. This really breaks down into two problems:

### Accessing the Marker Instance

First you need to get the marker somehow, either by selecting it through the DOM or accessing a reference (variable). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106797/how-can-i-get-a-leaflet-js-instance-using-only-a-dom-object) addresses the first of those 2 options and the code explains it more below.

### Retrieving the Coordinates

Next you need to actually get the coordinates from the instance. Mapbox depends on another, open source library called [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) which provides the method you need, `getLatLng`. [This Mapbox tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/select-center-form/) shows you how to use it but in a slightly different use case.

### Solution

At the end of the day your code could look something like this:

```
// Create Map
...

// Append Marker 
let instance = L.marker([lat, lng], { 
    // Marker options...
}).addTo(map)

// Add instance and ID to element
instance._icon.id = 'mymarker'
instance._icon.marker = instance
```

Now in your test:

```
// Grab the marker
let element = document.getElementById('mymarker')

// Retrieve the coordinates 
element.marker.getLatLng()
```

### Related Questions

[How can I get a LeafletJS instance using only a DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106797/how-can-i-get-a-leaflet-js-instance-using-only-a-dom-object)

[Mapbox Tutorial - Display latitude and longitude on marker movement](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/select-center-form/)

[Assign ID to Marker in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683871/assign-id-to-marker-in-leaflet/31032786#31032786) (Helps with DOM accessing and marker saving)